# Polymorphic Jackson deserialization by typeinfo not working with enums

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson, deserialization

I have the following class being the java representation of a JSON object:

```
public class Vehicle
{
   private VehicleType vehicleType;

   private VehicleConfiguration vehicleConfiguration;

   @JsonCreator
   public Vehicle( @JsonProperty("vehicleType")final VehicleType vehicleType,
         @JsonProperty("vehicleConfiguration")final VehicleConfiguration vehicleConfiguration )
   {
      this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
      this.vehicleConfiguration = vehicleConfiguration;
   }

   ...

   @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "vehicleType")
   @JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TruckConfiguration.class, name = "TRUCK"),
         @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CarConfiguration.class, name = "CAR") })
   public void setVehicleConfiguration(
         final VehicleConfiguration vehicleConfiguration )
   {
      this.vehicleConfiguration = vehicleConfiguration;
   }
}
```

I am using the vehicleType enum (having two values TRUCK and CAR), as an external property to tell the deserializer how I want the VehicleConfiguration abstract class to be deserialized: either to CarConfiguration or TruckConfiguration. 
Here are the other classes(boilerplate exluded):

```
public class CarConfiguration extends VehicleConfiguration
{
   private int numberOfDoors;


   @JsonCreator
   public CarConfiguration( @JsonProperty("numberOfDoors") final int numberOfDoors )
   {
      this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
   }
}
```

```
public class TruckConfiguration extends VehicleConfiguration
{
   private String manufacturer;


   @JsonCreator
   public TruckConfiguration( @JsonProperty("manufacturer") final String manufacturer )
   {
      this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
   }
}
```

My test is the following:

```
@Test
   public void given_when_then() throws IOException
   {
      // GIVEN
      final String json = "{\n"
            + "    \"vehicleType\": \"TRUCK\",\n"
            + "    \"vehicleConfiguration\": {\n"
            + "      \"manufacturer\": \"SCANIA\"\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "}";

      // WHEN
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.enableDefaultTyping();

      Vehicle vehicle = mapper.readValue(json, Vehicle.class);

      // THEN
      assertEquals((( TruckConfiguration ) vehicle.getVehicleConfiguration()).getManufacturer(), "SCANIA");
   }
```

It throws the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.test.Vehicle, problem: argument type mismatch
 at [Source: {
    "vehicleType": "TRUCK",
    "vehicleConfiguration": {
      "manufacturer": "SCANIA"
    }
}; line: 6, column: 1]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1441)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.wrapAsJsonMappingException(StdValueInstantiator.java:476)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.rewrapCtorProblem(StdValueInstantiator.java:495)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(ValueInstantiator.java:228)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.build(PropertyBasedCreator.java:135)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.ExternalTypeHandler.complete(ExternalTypeHandler.java:230)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeUsingPropertyBasedWithExternalTypeId(BeanDeserializer.java:937)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeWithExternalTypeId(BeanDeserializer.java:792)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:312)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2842)
    at com.test.VehicleTest.given_when_then(VehicleTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:274)
    ... 32 more
```

Seems that the problem is with the enum vehicleType as typeInfo: if I change this field to simple String, and run the same test it works with no problems. But in my design, I already have an enum which I need to use to differentiate the deserialization.

My temporary solution was to add a vehicleType field to the abstract VehicleConfiguration, and set the annotations directly on the abstract class, using JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY annotation. Like this it works even with the enum, but I am adding redundant info with the vehicleType field. 
So is this some bug of the deserializer, or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of googling, and struggle, managed to find a solution: deleted the constructor, and now everything works just fine.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum, please provide one working answer, not one non-working answer and a comment.